# iOS Bluetooth Low Energy emission rate

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Apologise for the probably use of the wrong word in my question but for the life of me I can't think of the right one.

Anyway, I've been playing about with the Bluetooth Low Energy and I'm trying to create something that is going to use the RSSI signal strength the BLE device emits. For this, I need it to emit its pulse multiple times per second.

Is there a way I can up the amount of times my devices either scan for a signal, or broadcast their signal through code on iOS devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no API for you to change the advertisement speed or radio power.

This aspect is fully controlled by the system. You can only start and stop the advertisement and add some metadata to the packets: device local name, advertised services, etc. Moreover, the contents of the advertisement packets will differ depending on whether your app is in the background or foreground and, additionally, in background it will be slowed down. These effects have been documented in various SO questions and in the header files.

If your clients are iOS applications, then they should use either the RSSI in the advertisement packets ([`centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManager%3adidDiscoverPeripheral%3aadvertisementData%3aRSSI%3a) method) or when connected, the [`readRSSI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/readRSSI) method on the peripheral object (just make sure you don't call it too often).